# authentication-manager from xml to java. Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How can I migrate the xml configuration below (spring security) to java configuration.

```
<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- SHA-256 values can be produced using 'echo n your_desired_password | sha256sum' (using normal *nix environments) -->
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="securityUserService" >
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
    </authentication-provider>    
</authentication-manager>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the registerAuthentication() method, something like:

```
 @Override
 protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
 }

@Bean public ShaPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() throws Exception {  
    return new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);  
}
```

source: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/spring-4-xml-to-annotation-configuration.html